# Failed to bind properties under logging.level.* or someproperty.*=some_value

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

After i migrated from Spring boot 1.5 to 2.x i have the below problem:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Failed to bind properties under logging.level to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>:

Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

In properties I have

```
logging.level.*=debug
```

It works if I go back to version 1.5.x 
Can anyone point me in the right way?

UPDATE :
The same problem happens when I use

```
someproperty.*=some_value
```

That means the `.*=` is not supported in SpringBoot 2.0 ?

Comment: are you trying to set the root level? `logging.level.root=debug` The arguments after the `level.` should be a package or the root logger that you want to configure. THis is likely cause by how bindings have changed in boot 2

Comment: I trying to use a `property.*` .. like `dosomestuf.*=true` and is not working

Comment: I'm looking for an answer for why this would happen when you're dealing with a java-based EXE file that hasn't changed in the slightest. Why would this error happen after a reboot if it has nothing to do with a code change?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to explicitly mention logger name, if you are using SpringBoot 2.x.x, which you can notice when you compare documentation of both the versions.

**[SpringBoot 2.0.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)**

> ... using `logging.level.<logger-name>=<level>` where level is one of
>   TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF. ...

Eg:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
```

**[SpringBoot 1.5.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)**

> ... `logging.level.*=LEVEL` where 'LEVEL' is one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO,
>   WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF...

Eg:

```
logging.level.*=WARN
```

Comment: The `property.otherproperty.*=default value` does not work anymore in SpringBoot 2.x

Comment: @CostelDRAGU Yes, that is exactly what I wrote in my answer. I didn't get what are you trying to say

Comment: also failing for logging.level=ERROR without .*

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that if you are using environment variables then be careful not to set it's name as "LOGGING_LEVEL".

So like, never do this:
logging.level.root=${LOGGING_LEVEL}

I say this cause spring as default sets your environment variables as properties internally and will understand ${LOGGING_LEVEL} as logging.level="actualEnvValue", which will cause the exact same error the OP had and can be quite misleading, I have been at it all day.

Anyway, just be sure to name your variable some other thing like MY_LOGGING_LEVEL or ENV_LOGGING_LEVEL or LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT.

This is the source that helped me:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1592

Answer (score 2):

Open Below Path

```
project_base_dir/src/main/resources/application.properties
```

and add below line

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working environment like Openshift libert 23.0.0.6 or higher them like given in link https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-liberty, in addition to Spring boot 2.x version and above, you can use the following in either .properties or .yaml file:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

Thanks